# This Python code to check if there is 007 order in a list does not work

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,0,0,7,11]
flag=0
flag1=0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==0:
        flag=1
    elif flag==1 and a[i]==0:
        flag1=1
    elif flag==1 and flag1==1 and a[i]==7:
        print(True)
    else:
        pass
```

This is one of the problem in udemy. Returns True if there is an order of 007.
MY OUTPUT:
[BLANK OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J009m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because for second 0, the `elif flag==1 and a[i]==0:` will not be executed but the `if a[i]==0:` will be executed. So, for first 0, flag will be set to 1 and for the second 0, the `if a[i]==0` will again be true. As a result, the `flag` will be again set to 1 without executing the desired `elif` block. You may want to change the `if` block like below -

```
if flag==0 and a[i]==0:
```

That way when `flag` is set to 1 once, the `if` block will not be executed but the `elif` will be executed. So, the whole code will be -

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if flag==0 and a[i]==0:
        flag=1
    elif flag==1 and a[i]==0:
        flag1=1
    elif flag==1 and flag1==1 and a[i]==7:
        print(True)
    else:
        pass
```

Btw, if your code needs to check if 007 comes in order without any number in between them, then this code will also not work.